# List Ethereum transactions to: and from: in one const

Tags: web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I would like to list all the transactions to and from my **ERC-20** Ethereum address, i can only seem to list to or from, but not both at the same time. Is there another filter I could use or way to re-structure the statement to obtain both values in one const? Thanks

```
const transactions = await Token123.getPastEvents('Transfer', { fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest', filter: { to: this.state.account } })
```

and

```
const transactions = await Token123.getPastEvents('Transfer', { fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest', filter: { from: this.state.account } })
```

Here is how I am viewing the results:

```
                  <tbody>
                { this.state.transactions.slice().reverse().map((tx, key) => {
                  return (
                    <tr key={key} >
                      <td>{tx.returnValues.to}</td>
                      <td>{window.web3.utils.fromWei(tx.returnValues.value.toString(), 'Ether')}</td>
                    </tr>
                  )
                }) }
              </tbody>
```

Using: **"web3": "1.0.0-beta.55"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this in one call with Web3, it is not supported yet. Using

```
const transactions = await Token123.getPastEvents('Transfer', { fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest', filter: { from: this.state.account, to: this.state.account } })
```

will result in an empty list, unless the account happened to have send some money to himself. Your only option with Web3 are doing two calls. If you care about performance, you could use something like https://quickblocks.io/. But mostly just looking in the last X blocks will be good enough.

Command to get all transactions in one variable in one line:

```
const transactions = (await Promise.all([Token123.getPastEvents('Transfer', { fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest', filter: { from: this.state.account } }), Token123.getPastEvents('Transfer', { fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest', filter: { to: this.state.account } })])).flat()
```

Comment: Any chance you could provide an example of populating const transactions using two calls? As long as const transactions has to: and from: it will solve the problem.

Comment: @Luc1d That should be easy, I have updated the answer above.

Comment: Thanks @soliditydeveloper, in your example, theres a missing ")" before .flat(), but once added, it does function. `filter: { to: this.state.account } })])).flat()`

Answer (score 0):

A way to re-structure the statement to "obtain both values in one const":

```
const transactions = [
   ...(await Token123.getPastEvents('Transfer', {fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest', filter: {from: this.state.account}})),
   ...(await Token123.getPastEvents('Transfer', {fromBlock: 0, toBlock: 'latest', filter: {to  : this.state.account}})),
]);
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [Etherscan APIs](https://etherscan.io/apis):

```
const Web3    = require("web3");
const request = require("request");

const API_KEY     = "..."; // get an etherscan api key at https://etherscan.io/login
const MAX_RESULTS = 1000;  // this is etherscan limit per request; do not change it

const BASE_URL = "http://api.etherscan.io/api"
               + "?module="       + "logs"
               + "&action="       + "getLogs"
               + "&apikey="       + API_KEY
               + "&address="      + Token123.options.address
               + "&topic0="       + Web3.utils.keccak256("Transfer(address,address,uint256)")
               + "&topic1="       + this.state.account
               + "&topic2="       + this.state.account
               + "&topic1_2_opr=" + "or";

function scan(fromBlock, numOfBlocks) {
    const toBlock = fromBlock + numOfBlocks - 1;
    if (fromBlock <= toBlock) {
        request(`${BASE_URL}&fromBlock=${fromBlock}&toBlock=${toBlock}`, {timeout: 10000}, function(error, response, body) {
            const parsed = parse(body);
            if (parsed.result) {
                if (parsed.result.length < MAX_RESULTS) {
                    console.log(`blocks ${fromBlock} + ${numOfBlocks}: error = ${error}, status = ${response.statusCode}, message = ${parsed.message}, result = ${parsed.result}`);
                    scan(toBlock + 1, numOfBlocks + 1);
                }
                else {
                    console.log(`blocks ${fromBlock} + ${numOfBlocks}: error = ${error}, status = ${response.statusCode}, message = ${parsed.message}, too many results; retrying...`);
                    scan(fromBlock, numOfBlocks >> 1);
                }
            }
            else {
                console.log(`blocks ${fromBlock} + ${numOfBlocks}: error = ${error}; retrying...`);
                scan(fromBlock, numOfBlocks);
            }
        });
    }
}

function parse(str) {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(str);
    }
    catch (error) {
        return {};
    }
}
```

Then call, for example, `scan(0, 9850000)`.

Note that:

- For the 1st parameter, you can optimize the performance of this script by using the number of the block at which `Token123` was deployed (instead of using `0`)
- For the 2nd parameter, you cannot use `"latest"` because it stands for "number of blocks"

**This script was tested with web3.js v1.2.1.**

Comment: Thanks @goodvibration, in the first part of your answer, if I add a "(" before await and ")" before .flat() the script functions, however it splits from: on top and to: on bottom of the list, is there a way to print a continuous list of to: & from: in chronological order instead of having the results split like that? This answer is close.

Comment: @Luc1d: You're confused. There is no `flat()` in my answer.

Comment: I added .flat() to your answer, else i get an error later: "TypeError: tx.returnValues is undefined" when I am listing the results on line: <td>{tx.returnValues.to}</td>.

Comment: @Luc1d: That part is outside the context of your question (i.e., it does not even appear in your question). Therefore, it is not a part of my answer (and neither should it be). Following that, and with regards to the rest of your question in the comment above, I believe that you should post it as a separate question with all the relevant details.

Comment: ok, can you tell me how you would list the results of the first part of your answer? So i can verify it.

Comment: @Luc1d: I don't understand what you mean by "list the results". My answer gives you a way to get all the relevant events (which you've called `transactions` for some reason) in a single array just like you've asked. These events ARE the results (of calling `getPastEvents`), which means that they are already given to you in a list (an array). How else do you want to list them?

Comment: I updated the question in case that helps.

Comment: @Luc1d: Like I said, I don't know what you mean by "listing the results". Do you want to print **every** value in it? Then use `JSON.stringify(transactions, null, 4)`. Do you want some specific values in it? Then please state exactly what values you want. And like I said, for the latter option it would be more suitable as a **separate question**.

Comment: @Luc1d: Also, please note that both of the answers that you were given have **answered your question**. So you cannot come with complaints about either one of these answers not solving **some other issue** in your system. Please learn how to post questions and when to accept answers here. And please don't alter or extend a question of yours after it's been answered.

Comment: You are right @goodvibration, thanks for the instruction.